# Trying to Run Ruby script in terminal but get ERROR

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run a ruby script to rename some files but I get the following error:

```
Eccleshall$ ruby rename.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- ftools (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from rename.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey, Jack, you've got an error here!

Comment: Can you post the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to script to say:

```
require "fileutils"
```

instead of

```
require "ftools"
```

`ftools` has been deprecated.